# ng serve build error after npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm getting the following error in my angular2 app with cmd `ng serve` after deleting the `node_modules` directory and building it new with `npm install`.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'common-tags'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/models/config.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

also `npm install common-tags` to add it manually does not work

Comment: are you facing this issue after upgrading to latest version of angular-cli??

Comment: I moved my project into a new repository. i unfortunately also committed the node_modules. Deleted the folder, ran `npm install` but after installing the packages the app won't start with `ng serve` - error as above.

Comment: can't run `ng version` either.

Comment: looks like you have not installed angular-cli globally.follow the steps as mentioned here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli. Refer `Updating angular-cli` section

Comment: ...... pls kill me. of course running `ng serve` requires `npm start` to be run first. not `angular-cli` or smh just figured that out, because none of the `ngs` worked.

Comment: actually I had the some problem but a different solution. After removing the `.lock` file and `node_modules` and reinstall the dependencies it works again

Comment: Happened to me as well after updating angular-cli. What was your solution ?

Comment: i think you should be create a new angular 2 project and then delete src file of new project and then copy and paste src file from your project in new project then you will get clear error.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you should update your angular-cli and clean the cache

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Note: I also had node-gyp install beforehand.